# Como obtener los indices de un arreglo

Tags: php

¿Como puedo obtener los indices del arreglo que tengo en el ejemplo?

```
<?php
   $arreglo = array(4,5,7,7,8);
   foreach($arreglo as $x){
       echo key($x) . "<br>";
   }
?>
```

Cuando ejecuto este script me sale un error del metodo key() que dice que solo acepta matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al recorrer el arreglo de esta forma le asigna la clave del elemento actual a la variable $clave en cada iteración.

```
$arreglo = array(4,5,7,7,8);
foreach($arreglo as $clave => $valor){
  echo "clave: ".$clave." y valor: ".$valor . "<br>";
}
```

Resultado

```
clave: 0 y valor: 4
clave: 1 y valor: 5
clave: 2 y valor: 7
clave: 3 y valor: 7
clave: 4 y valor: 8
```

[Documentación](https://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Por favor explica el código, responder con solo scripts se considera de baja calidad

Comment: @Aprendiz si, aunque el codigo es bien auto explicativo, indicado por nombres de variables claros para que se puedan entender. Ahora el problema no era tan complejo para para hacer un testamento en la respuesta.

Comment: Se pide por regla de la comunidad que las respuestas también vayan explicadas, igual esto lo lee un programador avanzado o un novato y les debe quedar claro a ambos

Comment: Ok. muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente +1...

Comment: yo prefiero `array_keys($array)` , [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 4):

Existe una función en php llamada array_keys que extrae los índices de un arreglo y además le puedes añadir una atributo extra para decirle a la función qué índices del array quieres saber. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php

```
$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```